# NetBeans error when running project. Main class name_of_project not found or couldn't be loaded

Tags: java, class, netbeans, runtime, project

First of all, thanks anyway for your help,
My problem is when I run one of my projects, from which I won't copy the code because it's way too large (about 7000 lines), but the code has no errors, and when running the project, NetBeans shows:
-Error, main class myname_of_project.Myname_of_javafile not found or not loaded.

If anyone knows which can be the problem... I have found something about CLASSPATH but don't know exactly what do I have to apply, but the most strange thing is this same project with a few less lines in the code, before applying one of my last changes in the code, NetBeans run it, with 0 errors and perfectly working... could be the length of the code a problem?

Thanks everyone and sorry if there's any big mistake unseen by me in my English writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, just found my own answer now, after asking this question just a few minutes ago.
Affirmatively, the error was produced because of the length of the code, more exactly because the length of one of the java methods, so I divided the largest method (which had approx. 7.000 lines, and the rest of the methods together just had 300 more or less..) and now I have a new method, having the old one with 3.500 lines and the new one with the other 3.500 lines, I've run the project and perfect!